What exactly is (should be) a “structure” for $L_2$ (language of 2nd-order arithmetic)?
From Simpson’s Subsystems of Second Order Arithmetic:

The language of second order arithmetic is a two-sorted language…Variables of the first sort are known as number variables…Variables of the second sort are known as set variables…Atomic formulas are $t_1 = t_2$, $t_1 < t_2$, and $t_1 \in X$ where $t_1$ and $t_2$ are numerical terms and $X$ is any set variable.

A bit later it says:

A model for $L_2$, also called a structure for $L_2$ or an $L_2$-structure, is an ordered 7-tuple $M = (|M|, \mathcal{S}_{M}, +_{M}, \cdot_{M}, 0_{M}, 1_{M}, <_{M})$

What doesn’t make sense to me is the lack of any mention of an interpretation for the “$\in$” relation in this definition of an $L_2$-structure (it mentions $<_{M}$, yet no $\in_{M}$)
Is this (as I suspect) simply an error in the book, or am I fundamentally misunderstanding something about what a “structure” is supposed to be?

I found links to an alleged errata page for the book, but the page has disappeared (and archive.org has been down the last couple days recovering from a DDoS attack)


Theories of arithmetic do not necessarily include any notions of set theory.  Second order theories in particular tend not to formally interpret their set theoretical notions, because if you do that you end up describing first-order set theory and lose the benefit of the second-order language.  Remember that the theory and the metatheory are not the same.

There are two different ways to interpret second-order theories, known as the standard semantics and the Henkin semantics, respectively. See this. Based on your quotations, it seems the book uses the standard semantics, in which case there is no need to specify domain of discourse for set variables or interpret the relation $\in$. Instead, the domain for set variables is automatically $\mathcal{P}(|M|)$, while $\in$ is automatically interpreted as the usual set membership relation between elements of $|M|$ and $\mathcal{P}(|M|)$.

It is only in Henkin semantics that the domain of discourse for set variables and the interpretation for the relation $\in$ might be needed. Though in the usual way the Henkin semantics is framed, an interpretation for $\in$ is still not necessary and it will still just be interpreted as the usual set membership relation. Henkin semantics is used in second-order arithmetic, but using Henkin semantics does have the drawback of effectively reducing things back to first-order logic.

When you say “usual set membership relation”, that seems to presuppose that there exists an antecedent “background” set theory. But I don’t think any such presupposition is being made here. In fact the introduction of the book poses second-order as an alternative foundational theory (alternative to set theory)  — I won’t type it all out here, but the introduction can be viewed for free on Google Books.

Furthermore, even when specifying models of set theory (within a given set universe $V$), it is (to my understanding), customary to specify $\mathfrak{M} = \langle M, E \rangle$, i.e. both a class $M$ and a membership relation $E$ on $M$ (because you’re not necessarily assuming a transitive model, the $E$ of the model isn’t necessarily the same as the $\in$ of the universe — see Jech, Set Theory). Surely specifying an interpretation of the membership relation of the model is no less important for models of 2nd-order arithmetic?

BTW, despite the name “second order arithmetic”, this appears to be formalized as a two-sorted first order theory (first sort is “natural numbers”, second sort is “sets of natural numbers”). Again, this is viewable on the first few pages on Google Books.

After staring at this some more and brainstorming different ways of “decoding” the vague language, I’m starting to suspect that the semantics of $\in$ is assumed to be implicit in $\mathcal{S}_{M}$ (the interpretation of the second sort). These lecture notes (2nd paragraph of pg. 2) seem much clearer in that they explicitly mention “an interpretation of $\in$” as a constituent of the “model $\mathfrak{M}$”

You've omitted the second half of the definition, where Simpson is clear about this.

Definition I.2.2 ($L_2$-structures). A model for $L_2$, also called a structure for $L_2$ or an $L_2$-structure, is an ordered $7$-tuple
$M = (|M|, \mathcal{S}_M , +_M, ·_M , 0_M , 1_M , <_M )$,
where $|M|$ is a set which serves as the range of the number variables, $\mathcal{S}_M$ is a set of subsets of $|M|$ serving as the range of the set variables, $+_M$ and $·_M$ are binary operations on $|M|$, $0_M$ and $1_M$ are distinguished elements of $|M|$, and $<_M$ is a binary relation on $|M|$.

The key point is that $\mathcal{S}_M$ is a set of subsets of $|M|$. Then there is no need to specify an interpretation $\in_M\subseteq |M|\times \mathcal{S}_M$ of the symbol $\in$, since we can just use the real $\in$ relation.
What might be confusing you is that this definition is more restrictive than the usual notion of structure for (many-sorted) first-order logic. If we consider the language $L_2$ to be a two-sorted first order language with sorts $N$ and $\mathcal{S}$ and symbols $\{+,\cdot,0,1,<,\in\}$, then the usual definitions of first-order logic would say that $L_2$-structure is an $8$-tuple $(|M|,\mathcal{S}_M,+_M,\cdot_M,0_M,1_M,<_M,\in_M)$ where $|M|$ and $\mathcal{S}_M$ are arbitrary sets and $\in_M$ is an arbitrary binary relation between $|M|$ and $\mathcal{S}_M$. Simpson's definition adds the extra conditions that $\mathcal{S}_M\subseteq \mathcal{P}(|M|)$ and $\in_M = \{(x,X)\mid x\in X\}$, and these are non-trivial restrictions on the semantics we're considering.
...But the restriction is not too non-trivial. Simpson's $L_2$-structures are obviously extensional, i.e., they always satisfy the sentence $\forall X\forall Y\, ((\forall x\, (x\in X\leftrightarrow x\in Y))\to X = Y)$. Conversely, suppose $M$ is an $L_2$-structure in the sense of first-order logic which satisfies extensionality. Then $M$ is isomorphic to an $L_2$-structure in Simpson's sense.
Indeed, for each $A\in \mathcal{S}_M$, let $A' = \{a\in |M| : M\models a\in A\}$, and let $\mathcal{S}'_M = \{A'\mid A\in \mathcal{S}_M\}$. Then $\mathcal{S}'_M\subseteq \mathcal{P}(|M|)$, the map $A\mapsto A'$ is a bijection $\mathcal{S}_M\to \mathcal{S}'_M$, and this bijection (together with the identity map on $|M|$) gives an isomorphism $(|M|,\mathcal{S}_M,\dots,\in_M)\cong (|M|,\mathcal{S}'_M,\dots,\in)$, where $\in$ is real set membership.
So Simpson's definition of $L_2$-structure amounts to enforcing extensionality at the level of the semantics. As long as we're only interested in extensional second-order theories, there is no harm in restricting attention to this simpler class of structures. It's analogous to the way that first-order semantics require $=$ to be interpreted as true equality.

In the comments, you write

When you say “usual set membership relation”, that seems to presuppose that there exists an antecedent “background” set theory. But I don’t think any such presupposition is being made here. In fact the introduction of the book poses second-order as an alternative foundational theory (alternative to set theory).

I think this is a pretty big misunderstanding of what Simpson writes in the introduction. If you don't think Simpson is presupposing a background set theory, what do you think he means when he writes "$|M|$ is a set..., $\mathcal{S}_M$ is a set of subsets of $|M|$..." in Definition I.2.2?
After reading the introduction, I don't seen any indication that Simpson is rejecting set theory in favor of second-order arithmetic as an alternative foundation. Rather, he's interested in studying questions about which set-theoretic principles are necessary to prove theorems about "ordinary" mathematics, and second-order arithmetic is a convenient language to investigate these questions. He writes "Since in ordinary mathematics the objects studied are almost always countable or separable, it would seem appropriate to consider a language in which countable objects occupy center stage".
But even if you do want to use second-order arithmetic as a foundational theory, there is a difference between using a foundational theory and studying its models. You're free to go ahead and prove theorems from the axioms of $\mathsf{RCA}_0$ or $\mathsf{ACA}_0$, and you never have to think about models at all!
It's when you want to turn around and do metamathematics (e.g., prove independence results or study definability questions) that it's useful to consider the models of a theory. And now you're not working in the object theory (like $\mathsf{RCA}_0$ or $\mathsf{ACA}_0$) anymore, you're working in your metatheory. And for traditional model-theoretic semantics, this metatheory had better include a background notion of set.

Is Simpson implicitly assuming that there is a ZFC universe within which the models of 2nd order arithmetic are being defined? Perhaps that’s the implication of how he defines the semantics of $\mathcal{S}_{M}$ — that is, by presupposing a notion of “sethood” (i.e. “sets of natural numbers”) which is antecedent to his exposition of 2nd-order arithmetic.

But (as I think you alluded to) it doesn’t have to be this way, does it? If we regard the elements of $\mathcal{S}{M}$ to be objects of an arbitrary second sort and $\in{M}$ to be an arbitrary relation realized by our $L_2$-structure (with the caveat that $\in_{M}$ must obey extensionality), then presumably 2nd-order arithmetic can “stand on its own” as a first order theory without needing to assume some prior foundational theory like ZFC? (in the same way that that simplified set theories don’t need to assume the prior existence of a ZFC universe)

With regard to models of $Z_2$ (and subsystems like $ACA_0$), it certainly makes sense to think of them as defined within a universe of some prior metatheory like $ZFC$. But a formal antecedent meta-theory doesn’t seem strictly necessary, is it? After all, $ZFC$ multiversism can study different $ZFC$ universes without needing to assume that these universes are actually models defined within some antecedent stronger formal metatheory (Morse-Kelley, or something?)

I suppose one “asymmetry” is that ZFC is a theory strong enough to define models of itself, i.e. you can construct a model of ZFC inside another “larger” model of ZFC, but (probably?) you can’t use $ACA_0$ as the formalism for defining an inner model of $ACA_0$

(1) The definition of $L_2$-structure is totally irrelevant to using $\mathsf{ACA}_0$ as a foundational theory. It can certainly stand on its own - you can prove theorems from the axioms of $\mathsf{ACA}_0$ - without ever defining "model". The same is true for $\mathsf{ZFC}$. Mathematicians happily prove theorems of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ without learning basic model theory. Stronger, I can take a formalist perspective and prove theorems of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ by "pushing symbols around" while holding the philosophical view that the concept of infinite set is incoherent.

(2) I don't understand why you think the "arbitrary second sort $\mathcal{S}_M$" approach relies less on set theory than the "set of subsets $\mathcal{S}_M$" approach. What is meant by "sets $|M|$ and $\mathcal{S}_M$" and even worse "arbitrary binary relation $\in_M\subseteq |M|\times \mathcal{S}_M$" if you don't have a prior notion of set?

(3) "Is Simpson implicitly assuming that there is a ZFC universe within which the models of 2nd order arithmetic are being defined?" Well... yes, but you make this sound like an exotic thing to do. Simpson is working in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ in exactly the same sense that any textbook in number theory or topology does. Mathematical logic is part of mathematics, and when people do mathematics, the default assumption (unless they clearly say otherwise) is that they're working within standard foundations.

I think this answers my original question. But this has brought to mind a related issue which I've spun off as a separate question here
